# Missing a step in Goals

Tags: google-analytics

Many of my class mates have problem with there Goals in Google Analytics. They can only view 2 steps when it's suppose to be 3 steps. They only have:

Step 1: Goal Description
Step 2: Goal details

When:

[image: How it's suppose to look like]

Anyone who knows how to add the first step which is Goal Set Up? Many thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Goal details destination is the goal, if you want intermediate steps you have to enable Funnel toggle.